# Android to AppEngine SSL Communication

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, ssl

I have a reasonably widely distributed Android Application and I'm getting some intermittent weirdness when the clients are attempting to connect to the server and send/receive data. The clients attempt to push up locally stored changes once every ten minutes.

I am attempting to connect to my version-dot-application.appspot.com URL. Generally, the system is working well; however, occasionally I will receive some SSL Exceptions in the logs. These include:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate 
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
```

reports also indicate:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x5152b758: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:651)
```

This is really perplexing, as it only happens occasionally and I've never seen it in a development or testing scenario. Does anyone have any insights or seen this behavior?

My current thinking is to swallow these exceptions and just attempt to sync on the next schedule, but that seems like a terrible idea.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!